# use props with laravel and vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

hi im using laravel with vuejs2
and this is my `App.vue` code

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Applications></Applications>
        {{page_title}}
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
    import Applications from '../components/Applications'

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        components: {
            Navbar, Applications
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                page_title: 'Main',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

every thing working so good so far ..
so in my routes.js i did this code

```js
{ path: '/settings', component: Settings},
```

and in my `Settings.Vue` i did this code

```vue
<template>
    <div>
        setting components
        {{page_title}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['page_title'],
        name: 'Settings',
    }
</script>
```

but i cant access `page_title` from the props what i want i access page_title from App.vue in Settings.vue
thanks a lot

Comment: I guess, you want to pass the page_title from Laravel blade. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass data to `<router-view>`:

```js
const Page = {
  template: "<div>Title: {{page_title}}</div>",
  props: ["page_title"]
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: "/",
    component: Page
  }]
});

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  template: "<router-view :page_title='page_title'></router-view>",
  data() {
    return {
      page_title: "It's magic!"
    };
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.1.6/dist/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```